# Cloudflare how to set default object when using S3 backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I am trying to use a combination of CloudFlare and AWS S3 service to host a static website. My issue is that I have an "index.html" file and navigating to the S3 URL directly:

```
http://srdan.nz.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
```

it loads the "index.html" file (note, no mention of "index.html" in the URL).

However, if I go to the custom domain URL:

http://srdan.nz

It returns an S3 XML listing of the bucket contents:

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Name>srdan.nz</Name><Prefix></Prefix><Marker></Marker><MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys><IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated><Contents><Key>index.html</Key><LastModified>2018-10-09T01:10:39.000Z</LastModified><ETag>&quot;f51109004d6b0518fad4c2f69d950a45&quot;</ETag><Size>133</Size><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents></ListBucketResult>
```

instead of the contents of "index.html".

Does anyone know why this is the case? How do I configure Cloudflare/S3 to make the "index.html" file the "default" thing to return if someone just enters the URL?

I've got a workaround where I add a custom "Page Rule" to Cloudflare to redirect "http://srdan.nz/" to "http://srdan.nz/index.html" however, I'd strongly prefer if it would just return the contents of "index.html" directly.

Comment: Please show your CloudFlare configuration -- how CloudFlare is configured to be pointing to the bucket.

Comment: Using a CNAME record to point "srdan.nz" to "srdan.nz.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com". I haven't added any other configuration

Comment: Change that record to point to `srdan.nz.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`.  The one you are using now is the REST endpoint.

Comment: That was it! Thank you Michael! :-) If you post that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The answer to this is as @Michael mentioned in the comments of the question, but I thought it deserved a writeup...*

Take the example domain `mybucket.com` that we'd like to use to serve the contents of our s3 bucket from via Cloudflare.

Whilst the following URL is valid for just accessing the contents of the S3 bucket mybucket.com.s3.amazonaws.com it's no good for referencing in our Cloudflare CNAME DNS record.

I think that one of the main problems is that the [Cloudflare documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-Cloudflare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-) doesn't show the correct **static website endpoint** as stated in the [AWS S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) for serving a static website from s3.

You might find that if you use the incorrect end point in your Cloudflare DNS, your domain will return something like the following response at the root instead of your default document as setup in the bucket settings:

[image: xml response]

### ANSWER: Use the static website endpoint

Ensure that the CNAME record that you set up uses the `-website-` equivalent endpoint:

> mybucket.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

The correct format is `<BUCKET NAME>.s3-website-<AWS REGION>.amazonaws.com`, but it can be found in the settings for your s3 bucket:

[image: s3 properties showing static hosting url]

**Don't use the others, incorrect ones include**

mybucket.com.s3.amazonaws.com

mybucket.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

NB: You'll need to set SSL in Cloudflare to 'Flexible' because 'Full' and 'Full(strict)' do not work.